# Delphi | Read beyond end of file

Tags: delphi, grid

Olá,

Estou a tentar recuperar alguma informação de um programa feito em Delphi.
Acontece quando tento ver uma lista ocorre o seguinte erro: "Read beyond end of file".

Em modo debug o código anda em torno deste pedaço de código:

```
assignfile(usersession.ftemp_eime,'D:\EIME_DATA\DATA\'+usersession.nome_fich);
rewrite(usersession.ftemp_eime);
assignfile(usersession.f_eime,'D:\EIME_DATA\equipamentos.xxi');
reset(usersession.f_eime);
  //..... do work...
if not eof(usersession.f_eime) then
begin
  while not eof(usersession.f_eime) do
 begin
  read(usersession.f_eime,usersession.eime);
  usersession.passa:=true;

  //estado
  if usersession.eime.estado=4 then usersession.passa:=false;

  if usersession.passa=true then
  begin
     //se está dentro dos parametros, escreve no ficheiro temporario
     usersession.eime.pos_temp:=(filepos(usersession.f_eime)-1);
     write(usersession.ftemp_eime,usersession.eime);
    end;
   end;    // while
 end;

 //FileMode :=fmOpenRead+fmShareDenyNone;
 //..... End Work
 closefile(usersession.f_eime);
 usersession.tamfich:=filesize(usersession.ftemp_eime);
 closefile(usersession.ftemp_eime);
```

Numa situação normal isto iria mostrar uma lista de material numa Grid.

Comment: Aparentemente, o programa não conseguiu carregar o arquivo e, consequentemente, está tentando escrever em uma posição inválida. Difícil saber só pelo código e sem conhecer a estrutura do usersession e dos arquivos.

Answer (score 1):

Você está lendo para dentro de uma variável "usersession.eime" que provavelmente tem uma estrutura. Se chegar no fim do arquivo e o conteúdo restante for menor que o tamanho dessa estrutura você terá o erro que indicou.

Tenha em mente, também, que não é possível, por exemplo, ter uma estrutura (variável composta), digamos com um inteiro e duas strings, e tentar gravar e ler essas variáveis de um arquivo diretamente. Read apenas carrega bytes do arquivo. A função não reconhece estruturas, apesar de poder reconhecer apenas strings (linhas) caso vc tenha declarado como "textfile".
Se precisar usar estruturas compostas, que tenham strings, defina com tamanho fixo (ex: `x : string[100]`).
Mas para usar estrutura você deve abrir o arquivo indicando o tamanho, por exemplo: `reset(usersession.f_eime, sizeof(usersession.eime));`

Nota: A linha "if not eof(usersession.f_eime) then" é inútil já que o  while (na linha seguinte) vai fazer o mesmo teste.